# How do I get a for loop to print out asterisks that form a pyramid with odd numbered rows?

Tags: c#

I'm learning the for loop and as I understand it works this way: first it initializes the first statement, then it checks the condition, does the things in the body and then iterates. But I don't seem to get how this code works.
Here's the code:

```
   using System;
    
       class MainClass {
          public static void Main (string[] args) {
            for(int row=0;row<7;row++){
              for(int num=0;2*num<13;num++){
                Console.Write("*");
              }
              Console.WriteLine();
            }
          }
        }
```

It was supposed to print this:

```
*
***
*****
*******
*********
***********
*************
```

Istead it prints

```
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That second loop should probably be using the `row` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue was not using the `row` variable in the condition check of the inner `for` loop, since the number of asterisks in each row is related to the row value.

The original logic does the same thing in every inner `for` loop, every time. `2*num<13` is basically the same as `num<6.5`, or really `num<7` for ints, meaning 7 asterisks are printed for each row.

```
int numberOfRows = 7;
for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
{
  for (int num = 0; num < 2 * row + 1; num++)
  {
    Console.Write("*");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

FWIW, the only reason I even answered is to provide an example that's easier to read and maintain than the other answers.  For example, here the `row` variable is named appropriately, illustrated by the use of a variable to contain the number of rows.  If you want more rows, change `numberOfRows`.  If you want a different number of asterisks on each row, change the condition in the inner `for` loop.

When dealing with `for` loops, it's a good idea to keep the names of variables used in the iterator and condition meaningful and easy to read, so that someone who reads it later (maybe even future you!) can more easily understand the logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
        for (int row = 1; row < 21; row += 2)
        {
            for (int num = 0; num < row; num ++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

The first loop creates the uneven number of asteriks (1, 3, 5, 7, etc) to print the second loop will print them.

Comment: WIll print the empty even lines?

Comment: @MihirDave: No there will be no empty lines because the first loop increments with 2 every itteration.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding why'd you do something is very imported in programming [Read this](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/for-loop) it may help, apart from that you could see the below solutions for your problem

```
// Loop through 1 to 7
for (int row = 1; row <= 7; row ++)
{
    // print astrick only if you have a odd row
    if(row%2 != 0)
    {
        for (int num = 0; num < row; num ++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    // print empty line for even rows
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```